# Browser services' container in Docker Swarm mode

Tags: nginx, docker, virtualbox, docker-machine, docker-swarm

I've created 3 vm using docker-machine:

```
docker-machine create -d virtualbox manager1
docker-machine create -d virtualbox worker1
docker-machine create -d virtualbox worker2
```

these are theirs ip:

```
docker-machine ls
NAME      ACTIVE   DRIVER       STATE     URL                         SWARM   DOCKER    ERRORS
manager   -        virtualbox   Running tcp://192.168.99.102:2376                                   v1.12.6
worker1   -        virtualbox   Running   tcp://192.168.99.100:2376           v1.13.0-rc5  
worker2   -        virtualbox   Running   tcp://192.168.99.101:2376           v1.13.0-rc5
```

Then `docker-machine ssh manager1`

and:

```
docker swarm init --advertise-addr 192.168.99.102:2377
```

then worker1 and worker2 join to the swarm.

Now i've created a overlay network as:

docker network create -d overlay skynet

and deployed a service in global mode (1 task for node):

`docker service create --name http --network skynet --mode global -p 8200:80 katacoda/docker-http-serve`r

And there is effectively 1 container (task) for node.

Now, i'd like accessind directly to my virtual host.. or, at least, i'd like browsing directly my service's container, because of i'd like developing a load balancer of my service with nginx.
For doing that, in my nginx conf file, i'd like to point to a specific service'container (i.e. now i have 3 node (1 manager and 2 workers) in global mode, so i have 3 tasks running-->i'd like to choose one of these 3 containers).
How can i do that?

[edit]: i can point to my swarm nodes simply browsing to :, i.e:

192.168.99.102:8200

but there is still internal load balancing.
I was thinking that, if i point to a specific swarm node, i'll use container inside that specific node. But nothing, for now.

Answer (score 0):

Docker is having  ingress load balancing.  Its a default load balancer.  you can use --endpoint-mode dnsrr command to do DNS load balancing.

If you want to use external load balance like nginx.  first you should start the Nginx container and copy the config file to the running container and replace the old one.  then it will point container published port and host.

Answer (score 0):

If you can a docker service in ***HOST+GLOBAL*** mode, you can use an external load balancer. Because through service **GLOBAL** mode, there is only 1 service task (so, a container) on each VM belonging to the swarm. Because of **HOST** mode, service task port is mapped to "host" (in this case, virtual host: the VM). In this way, an external load balancer (like nginx) can forward incoming requests to *IP_VM:MAPPED_PORT*. I hope 've been clear :)